# Finding the holomorphic function given it is harmonic in terms of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

This was a question that gave me the harmonic function $u$ and told me to find $v$, which I have done. However, it then asks me to find $f$ in terms of $z$ so $f(z) = ?$. I don't see an obvious way to find this in terms of $z$, and would like some help.
Information:
$f(x+iy) = x^3 - 3cx^2 y - 3xy^2 + cy^3 + i(cx^3 + 3x^2 y - 3cxy^2 - 3y^3)$.
Original info given:
Given $u(x,y) = x^3 + ax^2 y + bxy^2 + cy^3$ is harmonic, find $a,b,c$, where they are real numbers.

Comment: You didn't recognize $(1+ic)(x+iy)^3$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Unfortunately not... was there a way that allowed you to see that? Or was it just (really good) mental arithmetic?

Comment: Well, it's a homogeneous polynomial of degree 3, so it can be only a multiple of $(x+iy)^3$. You don't need that much mental arithmetic for the rest. :-)